# Is it better to include PHP processing code in my HTML documents, or should forms link to PHP scripts that redirect back to static pages?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on creating a website, and I'm new to PHP.

Is it better to have .html pages that for button `Onclick` will call Javascript which will link to a PHP page that communicates with the database and then returns back to the .html page?  In my mind this would make PHP a background language and you would never see a .php page in the URL.

Or is it better to make all my pages .php so the html and PHP code can work in the same page? Just curious because I don't notice a ton of .php URLs

Comment: Third option: Use all html extensions, then add a handler to parse html files containing PHP. (e.g. `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP and HTML are ***complementary*** not **competing** languages. PHP is used to create dynamic HTML which will be sent to the viewer.

The extensions don't make code php or html. HTML code in a `.php` file **is still HTML**. by renaming a file to `.php`, it is simply telling the apache server to look out for php tags `(<?php ?>)` and if it finds any to engage the php engine.

PHP handles the data and HTML is used to format the data. Often called the frontend (HTML) which is what people see, and the backend (the PHP) which is what does the work.

Comment: Good explanation. And with a little mod_rewrite, you can have any extension or no extension for your pages.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you don't notice a ton of `.php` URLs these days is not so much because of AJAX or other techniques, but because of SEO.

SEO ('search engine optimisation') experts currently believe that URLs should be as readable as semantic as possible. This means dropping any file extensions (because they're irrelevant to the user and to the content of the page), and expanding the URL with descriptive text (often taken from the title of the content).

This results in URLs like the one on this page -- ie `/questions/6387703/php-vs-html-which-extension-to-use` -- rather than `/questions.php?id=6387703`, which would have been how it would have been done in the past.

There are still plenty of using the older style URLs, but increasingly the newer style is becoming the norm, meaning that you won't see many sites with either `.php`, `.asp` or even `.html` extensions to their URLs.

The important point however, is that these sites are still working exactly the same way behind the scenes.

For most PHP sites, this means using a technology built into the Apache web server called 'mod_rewrite`, which takes the new user-friendly URL that was entered, and translates it into the old-style format expected by the PHP program. The PHP program itself still sees the URL exactly the same as it always was.

Hope that helps explain things.

Answer (score 0):

Just use .php.  If you don't want to see the file extension, use mod_rewrite or some other way to get rid of the extension in the URL.  A lot of places do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP (HTML is not a scripting language). If you don't want to see .php extensions, use the RewriteEngine in htaccess to rewrite certain URLs. Example: you can use RewriteRule to dynamically change the name of page.php to page.html.

You *could* use Javascript, but it's easier and faster in PHP.

Hope this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have php as a “background” language, but you can go in and out of php on the page.  You can also “fake out” the URL so that a user doesn’t know you’re on a php page.  I also like to use AJAX to make sure that the page doesn’t have to refresh to display database information to the user.